# Copy Constructor to transfer ownership of a unique_ptr

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, unique-ptr, ownership

I need to write a copy constructor that also transfer the ownership of a unique_ptr member of the object being copied. The situation is as follows:

```cpp
class C{
   // C class stuff       
};

class A{
public:
    public A();
    public A(const A& a);
private:
    std::unique_ptr<C> c_;
}

class B{

public:

    B(const A& b) : a_(a){}

private:
     A a_;


};
```

How should I implement the copy constructor for `A`?

Comment: So when you make a copy you want to make the original invalid?  I would suggest deleting the copy constructor and making the class movable only.

Comment: If with the original you mean the original object A yes it should be "transferref" as a member of class B. Can you please provide an example of that?

Comment: @Gabrielecswoosh Spend some time reading the questions/answers on the [tag:move-semantics] tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your intent or approach is wrong, I guess.

The copy-constructor is meant to create a *copy* of the argument, but since `unique_ptr` maintains sole ownership one cannot make a copy of it. You *could* in fact make the unique_ptr member `mutable` and then move the resource it points to in the copy-constructor but that would be absolutely insane (this is what `std::auto_ptr` does and this is why it's deprecated).

Therefore either you need to:

- add a move-constructor to A and B (+ make copy-constructor deleted)
- switch from `unique_ptr` to `shared_ptr`, but only if C is actually meant to be shared

There's also a third option, which is to make a copy of the object pointed to by the unique_ptr in A's copy-constructor, i.e.:

```
A::A(const A& a) : c_(std::unique_ptr<C>(a.c_ ? new C(*a.c_) : nullptr)) {
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't call the intent wrong. It is perfectly fine to create an interface modeling a *regular type* which the wrapped type cannot expose naturally.

Comment: I don't agree with you. you can copy an object which holds unique_ptr. for example, I might implement LinkedList class which holds unique_ptr as the pointer for the next element. does that mean I cannot or shouldn't copy a liked list? I might want to copy the linked list itself and save that copy in the unique_ptr of the copied object

Comment: @DavidHaim, but OP wants to transfer the ownership in copy-constructor - this is what the title of the question says. I consider it wrong approach.

Comment: @DavidHaim actually Adam Romanek is right because my intent is to transfer the ownership, not to copy the object pointed by the unique_ptr. May I ask an example of a move constructor for this example?

Comment: @Gabrielecswoosh, here you have: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/bbvgsx31iuofzF4s. Please note that the compiler generates the same code for you by default when you have a move-only type as a member, e.g. unique_ptr: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/7AlOoXZSOMOSLiFa (note no copy/move constructors in A and it still works as expected)

Comment: Thanks, actually I do have other member variables in A that are not move-only type (i.e., a float and a int), so I need to write it!

Answer (score 4):

Obviously you cannot just do an assignment of `std::unique_ptr`s as their assignment operator is deleted. This is intentional to force the programmer to define the behavior he wants.

1. The new item takes ownership of `c_`, invalidating the original item.
2. The new item makes a copy of `c_`, retaining the original items validity.
3. The new item shares ownership of `c_` so that both the new and original items reference the same object.

---

In **case 1** what you're looking for is a move constructor, and the default move constructor will work fine. So you don't need to write any code, you can just do:

```
A temp;
A foo(std::move(temp));
```

*Note that `temp` is invalid after it is moved.*

In **case 2** you'll need to add a custom copy constructor to `A` to create a copy of the original's `c_`:

```
A(const A& a):c_(new C(*(a.c_))){}
```

After defining this in `A` you can do:

```
A foo(A());
```

*Note that this depends upon `C`'s copy constructor being functional.*

In **case 3** you'll need to fundamentally change `A` from using a `std::unique_ptr` to using a `std::shared_ptr`, so the definition of `c_` would become:

```
std::shared_ptr<C> c_;
```

Your construction of `c_` would be identical to what you're already using for the `std::unique_ptr` version of `c_`. So just using the default implementations you could do:

```
A foo;
A bar(foo);
```

And now `foo` and `bar` point to the same `C` object, and share ownership of it. This shared object will not be deleted until all `shared_ptr`s referencing it have been deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, to

> **”** write a copy constructor that also transfer the ownership of a unique_ptr member of the object being copied

you can just do this:

```
class Bad
{
private:
    unique_ptr<int> p_;
public:
    Bad(): p_( new int(666) ) {}
    Bad( Bad& other )
       : p_( move( other.p_ ) )
    {}
};
```

Because a copy constructor can have also this signature, plus two more, in addition to the more conventional `Bad( const Bad& )`.

I named that class `Bad` because it's really bad, it just does not make sense to do this thing except as sabotage of someone else's code.

Instead of a copy constructor that doesn't copy,

- implement a move constructor that *moves*, or
- implement an ordinary copy constructor that *copies*, or
- change the class design to e.g. *shared ownership*.